# Unable to upload > 200 MB csv file using Python Drive API

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

I am trying to automate my daily tasks using drive API and I came across an error when I try to upload the larger files (> 300 MB CSV) whereas the following code is working for uploading the smaller files (<100 MB). Added that I am running the snippet in my Debian Linux VM and no issues from my VM end.

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
import os



gauth = GoogleAuth()
# Try to load saved client credentials if already done
gauth.LoadCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")


drive_path = '<drive_id>'

data_to_be_uploaded = "my_big_file.csv"
    
# Declared the variable so that it will be uploaded as per the last date
file1 = drive.CreateFile({'title': my_big_csv_data+'.csv',
                          'parents': [{'id': drive_path}]
                          })
file1.SetContentFile(data_to_be_uploaded)
file1.Upload()
```

The error as following

````
  File "test_code.py", line 72, in <module>
    file1.Upload()
  File "/usr/share/hunch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydrive/files.py", line 285, in Upload
    self._FilesInsert(param=param)
  File "/usr/share/hunch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 75, in _decorated
    return decoratee(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/hunch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydrive/files.py", line 369, in _FilesInsert
    http=self.http)
  File "/usr/share/hunch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/hunch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 810, in execute
    _, body = self.next_chunk(http=http, num_retries=num_retries)
  File "/usr/share/hunch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/hunch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 970, in next_chunk
    headers=headers)
  File "/usr/share/hunch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 175, in new_request
    redirections, connection_type)
  File "/usr/share/hunch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 282, in request
    connection_type=connection_type)
  File "/usr/share/hunch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1994, in request
    cachekey,
  File "/usr/share/hunch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1690, in _request
    content,
httplib2.RedirectMissingLocation: Redirected but the response is missing a Location: header.```
````

Comment: If the file size is an issue - why dont you try to compress the file?

Comment: @balderman: Tried that but the same error.

Comment: What is the file size after you compress it?

Comment: @balderman : It's around 50 MB. But still receiving error as  httplib2.RedirectMissingLocation: Redirected but the response is missing a Location: header.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59815620/gcloud-upload-httplib2-redirectmissinglocation-redirected-but-the-response-is-m

Comment: @balderman: Thanks solved by downgrading my httplib2 version to 0.13.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by downgrading my httplib2 package to 0.13.1

Reference used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59815620/gcloud-upload-httplib2-redirectmissinglocation-redirected-but-the-response-is-m)

Thanks ! @balderman

Answer (score 0):

There are 100MB limits on some types of files

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en